# Creating own ref-label system without using additional parameters using newcommand?

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

is there any possibility to create a command by to make a reference without using additional parameters?
I would use something like

`\newcommand{\something}[#1]{\label{#1}}`

Is it possible to do it without `#1`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Yes it is possible, by using automatic generated labels, but this depends on the surrounding code (which is not given by you `;-)`)

Comment: `\newcommand{\something}{\label{zzz}}` is legal and makes `\label{zzz}` every time you use the command. If that isn't what you want then you need to give at east a hint of what you do want.

Comment: Shouldn't the instruction read `\newcommand{\something}[1]{\label{#1}}` -- no `#` in front of the first `1`, right?

Comment: @Mico: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is very unspecific, I'll give an example for equations.  The one that conforms to your question is `\beql` which begins the equation environment and automatically assigns a label with the name `eq:x` where `x` is the equation number.

**Note that this kind of defeats the whole purpose of labels, as any system that automatically assigns labels will change if, for example, you insert a new labeled equation before the one already there.**  So while this does what you ask, it will be prone to breakage.  **Providing explicit labels is a far better approach!**

Just for completeness, I also provide `\beq` that starts an equation without the label.  The corresponding end-equation macros are `\eeq` to just end it, `\eeqc` to end it with a comma, and `\eeqp` to end it with a period.

```
\documentclass{article}
%       BEGIN EQUATION MODE
\newcommand{\beq}{\begin{equation}}
%       BEGIN EQUATION MODE WITH LABEL
\newcommand{\beql}{\begin{equation}\label{eq:\theequation}}
%       END EQUATION MODE
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{equation}}
%       END EQUATION MODE WITH A PERIOD
\newcommand{\eeqp}{\;\;\;.\end{equation}}
%       END EQUATION MODE WITH A COMMA
\newcommand{\eeqc}{\;\;\;,\end{equation}}
\begin{document}
Here I want a labeled equation
\beql
 E = mc^2
\eeqc
which ends in a comma.  Equation~\ref{eq:1} is not the same as
\beq
 y = mx + b
\eeqp
\end{document}
```

[image]